# d3.polygonArea() is not a function, which script to use

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg, polygon

I drew a polygon using d3.js and now I retrieved the area of the polygon using ***d3.polygonArea()***, and I have also use ***d3.behavior.drag()***
 function in my code for dragging purpose

So my problem now is that , I used the below script for my d3.js, and my d3.polygonArea(): is working properly-

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Next, when I use d3.behavior.drag(), I am getting error of:-

```
Cannot read property 'drag' of undefined
```

then I tried to add this below script  and the drag error gone but got error stating d3.polygonArea() is not a function:-

```
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/d3js/3.5.9/d3.min.js"></script>\
```

So my question is , which script should I use in my code? It look like if I use either one, then one of the function will not work.If I use both script also , either one of the function will not work.

**Script Example**

```
  <head>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/d3js/3.5.9/d3.min.js"></script>
  </head>
```

```
testData = [
              [32,35],[108,34],[108,110],[33,111]
            ];

var area = d3.polygonArea(testData1);
console.log('area-----------------',area);
```

```
// behaviors
var dragger = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on('drag', handleDrag)
    .on('dragend', function(d){
        dragging = false;
    });
```

Comment: `d3.polygonArea` is from D3 v4, while `d3.behaviour.drag` is from D3 v3. You **cannot** use both. You have to choose which version you want to use and, after that, change the corresponding method.

Comment: In v4, use [this syntax](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag) for drag, in v3, use [this syntax](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Polygon-Geom.md) for polygons.

Comment: hi @ccprog, i have tried to use version 4 syntax for drag, I am getting call(d3.drag('drag',handleDrag).on('end',endDrag)) is not a function. do u you have idea on how to call the drag function. polygonArea works fine